# Perl or Bash threadpool script?

Tags: multithreading, perl, bash, threadpool

I have a script - a linear list of commands - that takes a long time to run sequentially.  I would like to create a utility script (Perl, Bash or other available on Cygwin) that can read commands from any linear script and farm them out to a configurable number of parallel workers.

So if `myscript` is

```
command1
command2
command3
```

I can run:

```
threadpool -n 2 myscript
```

Two threads would be created, one commencing with `command1` and the other `command2`.  Whichever thread finishes its first job first would then run `command3`.

Before diving into Perl (it's been a long time) I thought I should ask the experts if something like this already exists.  I'm sure there should be something like this because it would be incredibly useful both for exploiting multi-CPU machines and for parallel network transfers (`wget` or `scp`).  I guess I don't know the right search terms.  Thanks!

Comment: How about this? http://www.rootninja.com/use-multiple-processors-in-bash-by-running-commands-in-parallel/

Comment: @carlpett Yes- you have the answer in there - `xargs -P`  Thank you.

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539310/does-a-modified-command-invocation-toolwhich-dynamically-regulates-a-job-pool (xargs does not play nice with many tools, e.g. unzip)

Comment: @daxim: thanks for the link; that was relevant. Re: `xargs` care to explain why it wouldn't '_play nice with unzip_'??

Comment: `$ /bin/ls -1 | xargs unzip␤Archive:  foo.zip␤caution: filename not matched:  bar.zip␤caution: filename not matched:  quux.zip`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441509/how-to-write-a-process-pool-bash-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl you can do this with [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new( 8 ); # number of jobs to run in parallel

open FILE, "<commands.txt" or die $!;
while ( my $cmd = <FILE> ) {
    $pm->start and next;
    system( $cmd );
    $pm->finish;
}
close FILE or die $!;

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need the output not to be mixed up (which `xargs -P` risks doing), then you can use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j2 ::: command1 command2 command3
```

Or if the commands are in a file:

```
cat file | parallel -j2
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 1):

There is xjobs which is better at separating individual job output then xargs -P.

http://www.maier-komor.de/xjobs.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [make](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_make.htm). [Here](http://teddziuba.com/2011/02/stupid-unix-tricks-workflow-control-with-gnu-make.html) is a very interesting article on how to use it creatively

Comment: In that case, scons would be a more versatile approach (and a bit less arcane)

Comment: Link is broken, but still available via the wayback machine :http://web.archive.org/web/20120509141639/http://teddziuba.com/2011/02/stupid-unix-tricks-workflow-control-with-gnu-make.html

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/7

```
# That's commands.txt file
echo Hello world
echo Goodbye world
echo Goodbye cruel world
```

cat commands.txt | xargs -I CMD --max-procs=3 bash -c CMD